# Label and Input text value is Overlapping each other

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate

I chose to use a full form to display the details of a selected record instead of the aspnetboilerplate default approach of using modals. But I hit a snag doing it as the records prefilled on the `input text` and `select` fields are overlapping. Then I tried to use this line of code `$.AdminBSB.input.activate($(this.bodyContent.nativeElement));` in the `ngOnInit()` but only the `select` fields were okay. The `input text` field values are still overlapping their labels. Please how do I solve this?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @aaron please are you familiar with asp.net boilerplate?

Comment: Quite. Start with a screenshot to show what you mean. Then list very detailed steps to reproduce your example.

Comment: normally aspnetboilerplate handles ui library initializations. if you've used a custom layout you have to check what abp is doing for a modal on init. you have all the sources you need.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu That's exactly what I did. I checked the modal to see what is done. I even went ahead to comment out the line of code to be sure that is what works. And I did the exact same thing in my layout but only the select dropdowns are affected.